# How to get updates from a working server to an app if its not running (Android Studio)

Tags: android, service, background

I'm working on an app that is very simple (it's a chat app)

I have a server and Android users.

for example say we have 2 users, user_a and user_b.
user_a enters a chat room and sends "hi user_b" (user_b is registered to this chat room)
when user_a sends his message, it is also sent to the server.

I'd like to make a service that will be running always in the background even when the app isn't running. that service will check for new updates each time.

so I'd like user_b to receive the message, and it will appear as notification.

in order to do it my approach is to make a service that will continuesly run in the background. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is sending messages to your server, which will notify recipients via GCM in real-time. You need to create a gcm intent service so you can catch gcm messages and handle them properly in your app (build a notification and updating chat activity)
You can also broadcast the messages you receive from gcm notifications so you update your chat online (like all chat apps do…)
I recommend you to read about [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) and [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: I was thinking of doing it via a broadcast and service, i haven't heard about GCM but ill check it out thanks!